# How to retrieve zendesk comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zendesk-api

I am working with the [Zendesk API Client](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb) gem and I am having trouble including comments in the reply I can retrieve the ticket but it doesn't include the comments to that ticket my code is below

```
ticket = ZendeskAPI::Ticket.find(client, id: 34798)
p ticket
```

and here is the response I am getting, is there something obvious I am missing here?

```
{  
   "ticket"   =>   {  
      "url"      =>"https://baopals.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/34798.json",
      "id"      =>34798,
      "external_id"      =>nil,
      "via"      =>      {  
         "channel"         =>"api",
         "source"         =>         {  
            "from"            =>            {  

            },
            "to"            =>            {  

            },
            "rel"            =>nil
         }
      },
      "created_at"      =>2017-11-17 09:49:11      UTC,
      "updated_at"      =>2017-11-17 09:49:49      UTC,
      "type"      =>nil,
      "subject"      =>"V2 test ticket",
      "raw_subject"      =>"V2 test ticket",
      "description"      =>"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111",
      "priority"      =>"normal",
      "status"      =>"open",
      "recipient"      =>nil,
      "requester_id"      =>15534722228,
      "submitter_id"      =>15534722228,
      "assignee_id"      =>nil,
      "organization_id"      =>13463857128,
      "group_id"      =>nil,
      "collaborator_ids"      =>      [  

      ],
      "follower_ids"      =>      [  

      ],
      "forum_topic_id"      =>nil,
      "problem_id"      =>nil,
      "has_incidents"      =>false,
      "is_public"      =>true,
      "due_at"      =>nil,
      "tags"      =>      [  

      ],
      "custom_fields"      =>      [  
         {  
            "id"            =>114097936533,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>114097989754,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>61510988,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>114097437574,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>58345127,
            "value"            =>nil
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>76165848,
            "value"            =>nil
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>61403888,
            "value"            =>nil
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>60446708,
            "value"            =>nil
         }
      ],
      "satisfaction_rating"      =>nil,
      "sharing_agreement_ids"      =>      [  

      ],
      "fields"      =>      [  
         {  
            "id"            =>114097936533,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>114097989754,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>61510988,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>114097437574,
            "value"            =>false
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>58345127,
            "value"            =>nil
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>76165848,
            "value"            =>nil
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>61403888,
            "value"            =>nil
         },
         {  
            "id"            =>60446708,
            "value"            =>nil
         }
      ],
      "brand_id"      =>3123448,
      "allow_channelback"      =>false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ticket Comments is actually a separate endpoint documented here - https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/ticket_comments

Looks like you may be able to use ticket.comments() to get the comments

Answer (score 0):

Not using Ruby to play with my data but using Python and the Comments are actuall the description and mine are all kind of merged together.  That's the only thing I have see so far.  Have you checked the API Docs for Ruby?